# Disable example of shipping method

Tags: commerce

Please tell me how to remove the example shipping method. If I disable this module, my other shipping methods also don't work. There is no option to disable or delete this. The only option is 'Configure Component'. I have even tried imposing a condition on Example Shipping Method 'that it must show up only if the order is too big' but still doesn't work. All shipping methods get disabled even if I add a condition on 'Example Shipping Method. '

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Shipping Method Example from the module list itself. I have never enabled that and my shipping method works. I have flat rate enabled for my shipping method. Simply disable the module. Here is the screenshot of my shipping modules tab -

[image]